# Integration of: $\frac{x}{\ln x}$

Tags: definite-integrals

I would like to ask some assistance with how to integrate : $\dfrac{x}{\ln x}$

I could really use an explanation and final answer.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You added the tag (definite-integral). In that case, which are the limits of integration?

Comment: Compute the power series expansion for $x/ln(x)$ pending the limits of integration, and then it's a simple integration. You can also change variables: $x=e^t$ to get an integral of the form: $e^{2t} / t$ which is more easy to expand in a power series.

Comment: Thank you-- im sorry.      between e^5 to e^6

Comment: About  e2t/t   , thank you for your answer but I don't seem to realize how to finish it from there, I ended up in a non-ending loop with that one

Answer (score 5):

Change the variable $x$ into $y=\ln x$, you get
$$\int^x\frac{u}{\ln u}\mathrm{d}u=\int^{\ln x}\frac{\mathrm{e}^{2y}}y\mathrm{d}y.$$
This is an so-called exponential integral $\mathrm{Ei}$. Thus the primitive of $x\mapsto x/\ln x$ is $x\mapsto\mathrm{Ei}(2\ln x)$.

Answer (score 4):

Set $\,y:=x^2\,$ then for $x>0$ :
\begin{align}
\int \frac{x\,dx}{\ln(x)}&=\int \frac{2\,x\,dx}{2\ln(x)}\\
&=\int \frac{d(x^2)}{\ln(x^2)}\\
&=\int \frac{dy}{\ln(y)}\\
&=\operatorname{li}(y)\\
&=\operatorname{li}\left(x^2\right)
\end{align}
with $\operatorname{li}$ the [logarithmic integral function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function) (corresponding to V. Rossetto's answer).

Comment: $\mathrm{Ei}(x)=\mathrm{li}(\mathrm{e}^x)$ indeed ! It's good to remember this identity, since $\mathrm{Ei}$ is implemented in the GNU Scientific Library (GSL) but $\mathrm{li}$ is not !

Comment: @V.Rossetto: I think too that $\mathrm{Ei}$ is more adapted for numerical evaluation than $\mathrm{li}$. One should merely take care that some implementations of the function '$\mathrm{Ei}$' implement in reality the [related $\mathrm{E_1}$ function](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101114/area-of-validity-of-writing-an-exponential-integral-as-sum-of-integralsinus-and).