# What is $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1} \text{Li}(a\ln(x))-\text{Li}(b\ln(x))$?

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

I have isolated my troubles with solving a larger question to this one part. For $a,b\in\mathbb{R}>1$

What is

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 1} \left[\text{Ei}(a\ln(x))-\text{Ei}(b\ln(x))\right]
$$

I have no idea where to even begin with this. It arose as I was trying to evaluate the definite integral of

$$
\iint_A x^ydxdy
$$

When the x bound was 1, you get the above shown indeterminate form that I can't figure out how to evaluate. Does Ei have some sort of property that allows it to become other functions in some way?

An equivalent form of the limit is

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 1} \left[\text{Li}(x^a)-\text{Li}(x^b)\right]
$$

Comment: Could you specify what kind of functions you're looking for in place of Ei/Li?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [Exponential integral](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialIntegral.html) and [logarithmic integral](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogarithmicIntegral.html)?

Comment: Potential hint: If $f(x) = \operatorname{Ei}(a \ln x) - \operatorname{Ei}(b \ln x)$, then $f'(x) = \frac{x^a - x^b}{x \ln x}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: if $x\to 1$ then $a\ln(x)\to 0\;$ so that you are searching $\operatorname{Ei}(a\ln x)-\operatorname{Ei}(b\ln x)$ for  parameters going to $0$.
The result should be : $\displaystyle\ln\frac ab$ from the expansion $6.6.1$ at [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/6.6) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101114) :
$$\operatorname{Ei}(z)=\gamma +\frac 12 \left(\ln z-\ln\frac 1z\right) +\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n!n}$$

Comment: I am not sure why your equation is different from the DLMF but using that I can confirm that $\ln(\frac{a}{b})$ is the correct answer as the constant cancels, the infinite sum goes to zero with the input being 0 when x=1, then what is left is the difference of natural logs which can be simplified such that the internal natural logs cancel, resulting in $\ln\frac{a}{b}$. Many thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped @ExodusSolis! I indicated Wolfram's formula that doesn't need the $z\ge 0$ hypothesis and handles the complex logarithm (the same at the end). Excellent continuation,